# How can I import 'createSpyObj' from jasmine for tests written in Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine, webstorm

How do I import the `createSpyObj` property from jasmine?

I have installed `@types/jasmine` and `jasmine-core` via npm.

I have tried importing jasmine as:

```
import jasmine from 'jasmine;
import { createSpyObj } from 'jasmine'; //triggers import error in IDE
import * as jasmine from 'jasmine'; //triggers import error in IDE
```

None of these allow me to access the `createSpyObj` without an error thrown in my WebStorm IDE.

[image: IDE error showing it cannot find 'createSpyObj' method on jasmine]

**More information:**

I see a namespace declaration for `createSpyObj` in the typings file. It is nested in the `jasmine` namespace. This is unlike `expect`, `it`, which are global declarations, but shouldn't I be able to access it with `jasmine.createSpyObj`?

[image: jasmine typings file]

Related, but not duplicate of

[How to import 'describe', 'expect' and 'it' into a typescript tests for IDE to not to highlight them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143700/how-to-import-describe-expect-and-it-into-a-typescript-tests-for-ide-to-n) and

[Unit testing using Jasmine and TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863565/unit-testing-using-jasmine-and-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

jasmine uses require syntax, so you must too.

```
import createSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj;
```